# Perl equivalent of grep -Eo

Tags: regex, perl

In shell scripting, `grep -Eo {regex} {file}` returns the matched part of the regex. For example:

```
$ echo \
'For support, visit <http://www.example1.com/support>
You can also visit <http://www.example2.com/products> for information.'
| grep -Eo 'http://[a-z0-9_.-]+/'

http://www.example1.com/
http://www.example2.com/
```

How would I do this with Perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways:

1. In Perl, the special variable `$&` contains the matched part of the regular expression.

   ```
   perl -ne 'print "$&\n" if m#http://[a-z0-9_.-]+/#' < input
   ```
2. If your regular expression contains capture groups, the patterns matched by those groups are assigned to the variables `$1`, `$2`, ...

   ```
   perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if m#(http://[a-z0-9_.-]+/)#' < input
   ```

Answer (score 2):

To get `-o` functionality I suggest the following:

```
echo abcdabcd | perl -lne 'while ($_ =~ s/(bc)//){print $1}'
bc
bc

echo abcdabcd | grep -Eo 'bc'
bc
bc
```

But for you example I suggest `perl -pe 's|(http://[\w-\.]+/).*|$1|g'`:

```
echo 'http://www.example1.com/support' | perl -pe 's|(http://[\w-\.]+/).*|$1|g'
http://www.example1.com/
```